# What is the best way to access the outer <this> from the inner nested constructor's prototype in JS classes?

Tags: javascript, nested, this, inner-classes, private-methods

Can we still not use a more elegant way than an archaic variable like `that` to access the outer `this` with nested classes and especially when private class fields are involved?

A simplified example to demonstrate could be;

```js
class Person {
  #Ofset;
  #H;
  constructor(name) {
    var that  = this;
    this.name = name;
    this.#H   = class {
                  constructor(n) {
                    that.#Ofset = Math.random();
                    this.age = n + that.#Ofset;
                  };
                  ofset() {return that.#Ofset}; // accessing outer class's private
                };                             // member from the inner class's
  };                                           // prototype
  setAge(n) {
    return new this.#H(n);
  }
};

var p = new Person("Joe").setAge(10);

console.log(p.age);     // 10.09289026855164
console.log(p.ofset()); // 0.09289026855163951
```

In my scenario the inner class instance should be able to get and set the outer class private field `#Ofset`.

So this works just fine like this but i would like to to know if there exists a more idiomatic solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you mean with *idiomatic*, but a cleaner and less complex way would be, to avoid the class and instead use an object and behavior delegation:

```
var Person = {
    
    Ofset: 0,
    name: "",
    age: 0,
    setName(name) { this.name = name; },
    getName() { return this.name; },
    setAge(n) { 
        this.Ofset = Math.random();
        this.age = n + this.Ofset; 
    },
    getAge() { return this.age; },
    getOfset() { return this.Ofset; }
    
};

var p = Object.create( Person );

p.setName("Joe");
p.setAge(10);
        
console.log(p.getAge());     // 10.09289026855164
console.log(p.getOfset());   // 0.09289026855163951
```

If you doesn't like the extra step *setName*, you could combine the methods:

```
...
    setData(name, n) { 
        this.setName(name);
        this.setAge(n);
    },
    getData() { 
        return {
            name: this.name,
            age: this.age,
            Ofset: this.Ofset
        };
    }

};

var p = Object.create( Person );
var m = Object.create( Person );

p.setData("Joe", 10);
m.setData("Mary", 300);
        
console.log(p.getAge());     // 10.09289026855164
console.log(p.getOfset());   // 0.09289026855163951
console.log(m.getData());    //>{name: "Mary", age: 300.67031318594286, Ofset: 0.6703131859428475}
```