# How to access the properties of a another class in a nested class in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, object, oop, parent-child

I have two classes, parent and child and I want the child class to access a method on the parent class in some way (note that child class doesn't extend/inherit from parent class)...
The parent class just has a property of the array of it's children objects.

```
class Parent {
  constructor() {
    this.name = "parent";
    this.children = [];
  }

  addChild(child) {
    this.children.push(child);
  }

  foo() {
    console.log("foo");
  }
}

class Child {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;

    // Call the foo function of the parent
  }

}
```

I also discovered an alternative approach:

```
class Child {
  constructor(name, parent) {
    this.name = name;
    this.parent = parent;
    this.parent.foo();
  }
}
```

But in the above approach, each child has its parent class as a property on it but the parent class also has the child property so, it would create a situation where the child contains the parent which contains the child which again contains the parent and so on.....
And I don't think that it is the best programming practice to have infinitely nested properties on an object, So I'm a bit hesitant to this approach.

I hope there is some other way to doing this, or is the infinitely nested property approach fine?

Comment: What do you mean by "the parent"? You can add the same child to multiple parents.

Comment: There's no automatic link to the object that contains a reference to another object. If you need that link, you have to make it explicitly, as in your second approach.

Comment: I believe in order to have a parent child relationship they must have been defined in a nested fashion such as the `Child` class should have been defined under the `Parent` class.

Comment: @Barmar So, is the second approach ok to use in terms of programming practices, because it gets the job done but I don't know if it will scale well as more child classes are added....

Comment: Yes, it's how you're supposed to do it.

Comment: @Redu could you please explain how that "nested fashion" works?

Comment: If you need to allow for multiple parents, `this.parents` could be an array.

Comment: In this particular case you can use `this.foo = Parent.prototype.foo`. As per nested class definitions, things might get a little convoluted. Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66663544/4543207) question.

Comment: @Redu `this.foo = Parent.prototype.foo` just copies the method from the parent class and the properties of the parent class still aren't accessible....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent-child relationship has to be established and maintained explicitly for each child. And since the `parent` property of each child instance/object is just a reference to a `Parent` instance, the OP does not need to worry about memory consumption or whatever it is, the OP refers to as *"nested"*.

```js
class Child {
  constructor(name, parent) {

    this.name = name;
    this.parent = parent;

    // Call the `foo` function of the parent
    // in case `parent.foo` exists and is callable.
    parent?.foo?.();
  }
}

class Parent {
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'parent';
    this.children = [];
  }

  addChild(referenceOrName) {
    if (typeof referenceOrName === 'string') {

      this.children.push(new Child(referenceOrName, this));
    } else if (
      (referenceOrName instanceof Child) &&
      !this.children.includes(referenceOrName)
      //!this.children.find(child => child.name === referenceOrName.name)
    ) {
      referenceOrName.parent = this;
      this.children.push(referenceOrName);
    }
  }

  foo() {
    console.log("foo");
  }
}

const testParent = new Parent;
const testChild = new Child('baz', testParent);

console.log({ testParent });

testParent.addChild('bar');
testParent.addChild(testChild);

console.log({ testParent });

testParent.addChild('biz');
testParent.addChild('boz');

console.log({ testParent });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: So, to sum it up, it is fine to have infinitely nested objects as long as the deeply nested properties are not called, right?

Comment: Nope. Twice. There is nothing deeply nested within a simple parent-child relationship and the child carrying a reference to its parent. Also references are not "expensive". And of cause accessing something constantly / heavily like `foo.bar.baz.biz.buz` is of cause more expensive than doing it via a reference like `const biz = foo.bar.baz.biz` and then constantly accessing `biz.buz`.